# using template function on vector of vector string , bubble sort only partially sorting

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, bubble-sort

my output is below, bubble sort partially sorting, 'Battle Start Galatica' is one string

before sorting,

> cats dogs monkey pear bears beat beets Battle Start Galatica bear
>   bears be bee zebra cantaloupe cactus

after sorting,

> bear bears be bears beat beets Battle Start Galatica bee zebra
>   cantaloupe cactus cats dogs monkey pear

Hello, World!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Sort.h"

int main() {
  std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > >
  v1{ {{"cats", "dogs", "monkey", "pear"}, {"bears", "beat", "beets", 
        "Battle Start Galatica"}},
      {{"bear", "bears", "be"}, {"bee", "zebra"}, {"cantaloupe", 
        "cactus"}}};

  std::cout << "before sort" << std::endl;
  std::cout << v1 << std::endl;

  sort(v1);

  std::cout << "after sort" << std::endl;
  std::cout << v1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

i turn the vector into a vector and try and sort it 
using bubble sort

```
template <typename T>
void sort(std::vector<T>& v)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < v.size();i++)
  {
      bool swapped = false;
      for(int j = 0; j < v.size()-i-1;j++)
      {
          if(v[j]>v[j+1])
          {
              swap(v,j,j+1);
              swapped = true;
          }
      }
      if(!swapped) break;
  }
}
```

with the following swap method

```
template <typename T>
void swap(std::vector<T>& v, int i, int j)
{
    T temp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = temp;
}
```

What method will sort completely or what method in addition to bubble?

Comment: I'd use std::sort myself;  or std::stable_sort depending on requirements

Comment: @UKMonkey Practicing building sort functions

Comment: You have 3 levels of vector and it is only sorting the first one. Remove the `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > >` and do just `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: Aside: take a look at [`iter_swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap) and [writing sort algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c)